# Ionic2 NavController popToRoot

Tags: ionic2

I am using Ionic 2 rc4.

I am trying to use the [NavController](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/navigation/NavController/) to go back to the root page.

I have:

`Page1 (root) -> Page2 -> Page3`

I use:

```
  this.nav.popToRoot().then(() => {
    this.events.publish('popupFilter:update', data);
  });
```

When I am on `Page3`, I expect it to pop to `Page1` However, it does not pop to the root, but rather only one page back (`Page2`).

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Secondly, how can I see what pages are in the stack?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set root page rather than pop. try to use following command

```
    this.navCtrl.push(root);
```

i hope its work for you.